# Native View Within MasterDetailPage Xamarin Android

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a map view I am trying to create but it is a bit more advanced than the map implementation
provided by Xamarin.Forms. I am wondering if there is a pattern for embedding a native view withing
a master detail page.

In the example image the top navigation bar would be built in Xamarin and the content part highlighted in purple should be created individually per platform.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically where a Renderer could take over.

See [Customizing Controls for Each Platform](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) and the [Forms2Native](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Forms2Native) sample.

You would create a MapContentPage that would extend ContentPage and have a attribute on top :

> [assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (MapContentPage), typeof (MapContentPageRenderer))]

then you'd create a renderer for Android called MapContentPageRenderer and in its OnElementChanged, you would instanciate the map using 'regular' Mono for Android code.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement a custom renderer to create the custom map implementation in your own control, as the **Xamarin.Forms** **Map** control is rather limited at present as you are already aware.

Each renderer is targetted towards a specific platform (**iOS, Android, Windows Phone**).  So for instance with **Android** you will create a custom renderer based on the platform specific map control for **Android** etc.

You will then be able to build up functionality for each platform-specific control renderer based on your common **View** which will expose your model you want the **Xamarin.Forms** page to use.

There is a useful video [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/videos/cross-platform/xamarinforms-custom-renderers/) that goes into depth about how to create custom renderers that you may find useful.

Basically anything you can do on the **Android** platform etc can be put into a custom renderer so you can then use this as part of a cross platform **Xamarin.Forms** page.